# MySQL Join clause in Update

Tags: mysql, sql

When trying to perform this query:

```
>mysql_query("UPDATE contracts 
              SET x = '1' 
              FROM contracts 
              INNER JOIN employees 
              ON contracts.contract_employeeid=employees.employee_id 
              WHERE experience >= '6'") or die(mysql_error());
```

I get the following error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near FROM contracts INNER JOIN employees ON contracts.contract_employeeid=employees.employee_id WHERE experience >= '6'

In words, I need to set x=1 on the table "contracts" for the employees who have more than 6 years of experience (to do so, I need to join with the table "employees" on employee_id=contract_employeeid since their experience is stored in that table)

Comment: Extract the SQL and run it directly against the database to narrow down the problem a bit on where the syntax issue lies

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can probably move the JOIN part of your query before the SET statements:

```
UPDATE contracts
INNER JOIN employees ON contracts.contract_employeeid = employees.employee_id
SET x = '1'
WHERE experience >= '6'
```

Comment: Works fine and somehow quicker than Joe Stefanelli's solution (althought I don't know why). Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am not sure either. Both queries are equivalent AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE contracts, employees
    SET contracts.x = '1'
    WHERE contracts.contract_employeeid=employees.employee_id
        AND employees.experience >= '6'
```